# Integral $\frac{1}{\cos^2(z)}$

Tags: complex-analysis, analysis

How can I calculate $$\int_{\lvert z-i \rvert = 2} \frac{1}{\cos^2(z)}$$

My first attempt was to use residues: I have figured out that $z=\pm \pi/2$ is a pole of order $2$, so I tried to apply [this formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Residue_(complex_analysis)#Limit_formula_for_higher_order_poles), but the limit diverges.

I have also tried to write $f$ as Laurent-series to get $a_{-1} $, which is my residue, unfortunately I wasn't sucessful with that.

Comment: I cheated and CAS told me the answer is $2\pi \sec^2i$ so if you do figure it you have something to compare it with. The answer is independent of the radius of your circle (in general it was $2\pi\sec^2a$ where $a$ is the complex offset of the center of the circle) so looking at your residues seems like the right idea but its been too long since I've done them to help you.

Comment: How can the loop integral of a holomorphic function vary smoothly if you shift the position of the loop?